# Rails weird Characters in address bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, facebook

I'm using facebook connect in a RoR application. The connection works fine, but when the callback returns, the address of the page changes to something like "127.0.0.1:3000/_=_"

There's nothing wrong with the content and nothing else seems affected, but the URL shouldn't be like this, should it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same URL when I have a callback from Facebook (using OmniAuth) and I've also seen the same URL in other non-rails apps. It's because of the session redirect behaviour from Facebook. See this blog post: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/